# cannot load such file ../xray-rails-0.1.17/lib/xray/middleware when running 'rails server'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm receiving this error when trying to run any rails or rake command.

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xray-rails-0.1.17/lib/xray-rails.rb:5:in `require_relative': cannot load such file -- /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xray-rails-0.1.17/lib/xray/middleware (LoadError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xray-rails-0.1.17/lib/xray-rails.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like not only experienced this. [Here](https://github.com/brentd/xray-rails/issues/59) is same issue.

I suggest you to downgrade xray-rails to 0.1.16 or try to figure out by yourself whats going on and why middleware not loaded.